# MVC ViewResult.VIewName null even after setting it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, viewresult

I'm trying to write unit tests for a MVC application. im trying to test if my controller returns the correct view name.

This is the controller action im testing:

```
public IActionResult Index(string reportcode)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportcode))
          ReportCode = reportcode;

     ViewBag.GridSource = GetReportData(reportcode);
     return View("Index");
}
```

This is my Unittest:

```
[Test]
public void Index_ReturnCorrectView()
{
    var controller = new HomeController();
    var result = controller.Index("COMD") as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName); 
}
```

The error i get from the unit test is expected "Index" but got null.
I did a lot of search and most answers say the ViewName property should be set after you declare it when returning the view. I tried the same but it wont work still.

Thank you

Comment: Unrelated: You probably actually want `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportcode))`

Comment: Is `result` itself not null?

Comment: @Andrei no result is a valid ViewResult

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for Controller.View()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View) states:

> This method overload of the View class **returns a ViewResult object
>   that has an empty ViewName property**. If you are writing unit tests for
>   controller actions, take into account the empty ViewName property for
>   unit tests that do not take a string view name.
>
> At run time, if the ViewName property is empty, the current action
>   name is used in place of the ViewName property.

So when expecting a view with the same name as the current action we can just test that it's an empty string.

Alternatively, the Controller.View(ViewName, Model) method will set the ViewName.

My Controller Method

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View("Index");
    }
```

Test Method

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {
        // Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result.ViewName == "Index");
    }
```

Comment: Controller.View(String) is exactly what OP is using

Comment: @Andrei OP have to use like Controller.View("Index", "COMD")

Comment: @PowerStar Hi thank you for the reply. Im not really sure what you mean by Controller.View("Index", "COMD").  Is this what i shoud return in the index method? I dont see how it's different from my current implementation since there is no need to return "COMD"

Comment: @PowerStar alright so this passed the test! However I am still a bit confused. Does this actually call the index method from my controller? it seems to me its just creating a new view object with name index, if so it defeats the purpose of unit-testing

Comment: @7uner I am getting expected value in my test controller